# Reset modified state of entity in OnObjectMaterialized

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext

When I save an entity to the database I encrypt the values in an OnSavingChanges event handler. When the entity is loaded back from the database I'm using OnObjectMaterialized to decrypt the values.

This works great except that if I call save on one of the entities after its been materialized, the object context thinks that the entity has been modified and saves it back to the database.

So how do I reset the modified state such that it thinks that the decrypted values are the values in the database?